# VS Code APEX CLI test method debugging

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I am using the attached test class which contains one method (**testManualApprovalProcessManuallyApproved**) to debug my code.

I have turned on/off the apex debugger then got the debug logs and run the replay debugger to check my code, I have put a lot of break points between the Test.startTest(); and test.stopTest(); in the code below however when I run my replay debugger and step into the Test.startTest(); the debugger jump all the break points and finish the whole unit test method.

Is there a way to debug line by line between Test.startTest(); and test.stopTest();

```
    @isTest
public class PPAndLoanApprovalProcessTest_NEW {
    /**
* @name setup
* @parm 
* @desc test set up method
* @version 1.0
* @author : Someone
**/
    @testsetup
    private static void setUp() {
        Test.startTest();
        LogSeverityLevelValue__c logLevelSettings = TestDataFactorySFN.createLoggingLevel();
        Database.upsert(logLevelSettings);
        //Switch on the triggers
        List<Trigger_Bypass__c> tSwitch = TestDataFactorySFN.createTriggerSwitch();              
        Database.insert(tSwitch);
        List<Account> listAccBus = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> listAccInd = new List<Account>();
        Profile p= [SELECT Id From Profile WHERE Name='nTest' OR Name='nTest2' LIMIT 1];
        User smevsde = [SELECT Id FROM user WHERE profileid = : p.Id and IsActive = true LIMIT 1];
        system.debug('setup smevsde-->' + smevsde.Id);

        //insert Product structure matrix
        Product_StructureMatrix__c prdstm = new Product_StructureMatrix__c();
        prdstm.Name='987654321';
        prdstm.Product__c='Commercial (VR)';
        prdstm.Product_Type__c='SME - Term loan';
        prdstm.Product_Type_ID__c='123456789';
        prdstm.Segment__c='SME';
        insert prdstm;
        Product_StructureMatrix__c prdstm2 = new Product_StructureMatrix__c();
        prdstm2.Name='987654321';
        prdstm2.Product__c='Commercial';
        prdstm2.Product_Type__c='SME - Line of credit';
        prdstm2.Product_Type_ID__c='123456789';
        prdstm2.Segment__c='SME';
        insert prdstm2;


        system.runAs(smevsde){

            //Create Business Accounts
            listAccBus = SystemTestDataFactory.createTestAccounts(1);

            //Create Opportunity from Business Account
            /**Method Definition : SystemTestDataFactory.oppcreate(Account Id,Name,Stage,Loss Reason,Product Line, Product Type,
            Product, Amount, Source, Type)
            **/
            Integer NoOfOpps = 0;
            List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
            oppList.add(SystemTestDataFactory.oppcreate(listAccBus[0].Id, 'TestOpportunity', 'Proposed', 
                                     'NBC – Risk','SME','SME - Term loan','Commercial (VR)',500.00,'Prospecting','Increase'));

            oppList.add(SystemTestDataFactory.oppcreate(listAccBus[0].Id, 'TestOpportunity', 'Proposed', 
                                     'NBC – Risk','SME','SME - Line of credit','Commercial',500.00,'Prospecting','Increase'));
            NoOfOpps=oppList.size();
            if(!oppList.isEmpty()){
                Database.insert(oppList);
            }
            //Create Disbusrement Forecast
            List<Disbursement_Forecast__c> disbForecast = TestDataFactorySFN.createDisbursementForecast(1,oppList.get(0).Id);
            List<Disbursement_Forecast__c> disbForecast2 = TestDataFactorySFN.createDisbursementForecast(1,oppList.get(1).Id);

            //Create Product Package
            List<LLC_BI__Product_Package__c>  prodpackaglist = SystemTestDataFactory.createProdPkg(1);
            Database.insert(prodpackaglist);

            //Create Loan linked and link it to PP
            StaticTriggerValues.isLoanUpdateFromUI = false;
            List<LLC_BI__Loan__c> loanList = new List<LLC_BI__Loan__c>();
            loanList = SystemTestDataFactory.createLoans(noOfOpps,prodpackaglist.get(0).Id,oppList,listAccBus.get(0).Id);

            //Update the opportunities with created loans
            for(integer i=0;i<noOfOpps;i++){
                oppList.get(i).LLC_BI__Loan__c = loanList.get(i).Id;    
            }
            if(!oppList.isEmpty()){
                Database.update(oppList);
            }
        }


    }



    /**
    *Method Name: testManualApprovalProcessManuallyApproved
    *Description: This method will test approval process manually approved scenario.
    **/
    @isTest
    private static void testManualApprovalProcessManuallyApproved(){
         //Given
        Profile p= [SELECT Id From Profile WHERE Name='nTest' OR Name='nTest2' LIMIT 1];
        Profile p1= [SELECT Id From Profile WHERE Name='nTest3'];
        User smevsde = [SELECT Id FROM user WHERE profileid = : p.Id and IsActive = true LIMIT 1];
        system.debug('method smevsde-->' + smevsde.Id);
        User credoff = [SELECT Id FROM user WHERE profileid = : p1.Id and IsActive = true LIMIT 1];
        Id crdOffQId = [SELECT Id from Group where Name =: System.Label.SFN_Credit_Team_Queue and Type
                      =: System.Label.SFN_Queue limit 1][0].Id;

        LLC_BI__Product_Package__c  pplist = [SELECT Id,LLC_BI__Status__c, OwnerId, Assigned_to_Me__c FROM 
                                                      LLC_BI__Product_Package__c LIMIT 1];
        pplist.LLC_BI__Status__c = 'Open';
        pplist.LLC_BI__Reviewable_Loan_Facilities_Count__c = 1;
        ProductPackages.isFirstTime = true;
        StaticTriggerValues.ppAfterUpdate = true;
        Database.update(pplist);

        List<LLC_BI__Loan__c> loansList = [SELECT Id, LLC_BI__Stage__c, LLC_BI__Status__c,LLC_BI__Is_Review_Ready__c, OwnerId, LLC_BI__Product_Package__c 
                                    FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c WHERE LLC_BI__Product_Package__c =: pplist.Id ];
        for(Integer i=0;i<loansList.size();i++){
            loansList.get(i).LLC_BI__Stage__c = 'Underwriting';
        }
        //Loans.isCalledFirstTime = true;
        Database.update(loansList);



        Test.startTest();
        //Create an approval request
        //When
        System.runAs(smevsde){
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
            req1.setObjectId(pplist.Id);
            StaticTriggerValues.ppAfterUpdate = true;
            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
            System.assert(result.isSuccess());
            List<Id> newWorkItemIds = result.getNewWorkItemIds();
            List<Id> newWorkItemIds2 = new List<Id>();
            List<Id> newWorkItemIds3 = new List<Id>();
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req21 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            for(Integer i=0;i<1;i++){
                req2.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
                req2.setObjectId(loansList[i].Id);
                Loans.isCalledFirstTime = true;
                Approval.ProcessResult result2 = Approval.process(req2);
                System.assert(result2.isSuccess());
                newWorkItemIds2 = result2.getNewWorkitemIds();
                req21.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
                req21.setObjectId(loansList[i+1].Id);
                Loans.isCalledFirstTime = true;
                Approval.ProcessResult result21 = Approval.process(req21);
                System.assert(result21.isSuccess());
                newWorkItemIds3 = result21.getNewWorkitemIds();
            }
            system.debug('newWorkItemIds2-->' + newWorkItemIds2);
            system.debug('newWorkItemIds3-->' + newWorkItemIds3);
            System.debug('Loans stage after approval submit-->' + loansList.get(0).LLC_BI__Stage__c);
            //System.debug('Loans stage after approval submit-->' + loansList.get(1).LLC_BI__Stage__c);
            ProductPackages.isFirstTime = true;
                system.debug('newWorkItemIds-->' + newWorkItemIds);
                System.runAs(credoff){
                    system.debug('credoff user Id' + credoff.Id);
                    pplist.Assigned_to_Me__c = credoff.Id;
                    ppList.OwnerId = credoff.Id;
                    Database.update(pplist);
                    system.debug('Assigned owner PP--' + pplist.OwnerId);                  
                    system.debug('Assigned owner Loan--' + loansList.get(0).OwnerId);
                    system.debug('Assigned owner Loan--' + loansList.get(1).OwnerId);
                    Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest req3 = new Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest();
                    req3.setComments('Approving request.');
                    req3.setAction('Approve');
                    req3.setWorkItemId(newWorkItemIds.get(0));
                    system.debug('req3.setWorkItemId-->' + newWorkItemIds.get(0));
                    StaticTriggerValues.ppAfterUpdate = true;
                    Approval.ProcessResult result3 = Approval.process(req3);
                    System.assert(result3.isSuccess(), 'Result Status 3:'+result3.isSuccess());
                    system.debug('Result Status 3: ' + result3);
                    system.debug('newWorkItemIds2 size--' + newWorkItemIds2.size());
                    for(Integer i=0;i<newWorkItemIds2.size();i++){
                        Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest req4 = new Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest();
                        req4.setComments('Approving request.');
                        req4.setAction('Approve');
                        req4.setWorkItemId(newWorkItemIds2.get(i));
                        system.debug('req4.setWorkItemId-->' + newWorkItemIds2.get(i));
                        //Loans.isCalledFirstTime = true;
                        Approval.ProcessResult result4 = Approval.process(req4);
                        system.debug('result4-->' + result4);
                        System.assert(result4.isSuccess(), 'Result Status 4:'+result4.isSuccess());
                    }
                    for(Integer i=0;i<newWorkItemIds3.size();i++){
                        Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest req5 = new Approval.ProcessWorkItemRequest();
                        req5.setComments('Approving request.');
                        req5.setAction('Approve');
                        req5.setWorkItemId(newWorkItemIds3.get(i));
                        system.debug('req5.setWorkItemId-->' + newWorkItemIds3.get(i));
                        //Loans.isCalledFirstTime = true;
                        Approval.ProcessResult result5 = Approval.process(req5);
                        system.debug('result4-->' + result5);
                        System.assert(result5.isSuccess(), 'Result Status 5:'+result5.isSuccess());
                    }
                }
        }

            //Then
         test.stopTest();   
            LLC_BI__Product_Package__c ppNewList = [SELECT Id, LLc_BI__Status__c, OwnerId FROM LLC_BI__Product_Package__c
                                                   LIMIT 1];
            system.assertEquals('Manually Approved', ppNewList.LLC_BI__Status__c);
            system.assertEquals(smevsde.Id, ppNewList.OwnerId);

            List<LLC_BI__Loan__c> loanListNew = [SELECT Id, LLC_BI__Stage__c, OwnerId, LLC_BI__Product_Package__c 
                                        FROM LLC_BI__Loan__c WHERE LLC_BI__Product_Package__c =: ppNewList.Id LIMIT 100];
            for(Integer i=0;i<loanListNew.size();i++){
                system.assertEquals('Pre-Closing', loanListNew.get(i).LLC_BI__Stage__c);
                system.assertEquals(smevsde.Id, loanListNew.get(i).OwnerId);
            }       
        }
```

Comment: hello everyone, any idea

Comment: You can not debug line by line in Salesforce.
You need to put debug log at multiple lines, run check logs.
If issue not resolved, repeat the above process with additional debug logs.

Comment: that's false, you can with the apex debugger on VSCode